# condition $\mu ^*(B\cup C)=\mu ^*(B)+\mu ^*(C)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu ^*$ be an outer measure on $X$, $A\subseteq X$ and for every $B\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq A^c$ we have: $$\mu ^*(B\cup C)=\mu ^*(B)+\mu ^*(C)$$ Is this condition is equivalent with measurability of $A$?or is stranger ?or weaker?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Does it seem stronger/weaker for any particular reason?

Comment: @Clayton,it seem that is stronger

Comment: (I'm neither agreeing nor disagreeing) Why do you think it is stronger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent. Here are some hints for the proof:

- If $A\subseteq X$, then for any $F\subseteq X$ we have $F=(F\cap A)\cup(F\setminus A)$, where $F\cap A\subseteq A$ and $F\setminus A\subseteq A^{c}$. Use this to conclude that the stated condition implies measurability of $A$.
- Assume that $A$ is measurable, and apply the measurability of $A$ to the test set $F=B\cup C$. Note that $(B\cup C)\setminus A=C$ and $(B\cup C)\cap A=B$ to conclude that the stated condition holds.